# List of Online Users and Their Current Page?

Tags: members

Is it possible to get a list of logged in members along with the page that they are currently on? If possible, I'd like to filter this by page (meaning, I pass the URL of the page and I get back a list of users currently on that page). I need to display this information in the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Continuum](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/continuum) add-on. Note that it is still in beta, though it's at version 0.9 at this point so I imagine it will go prime-time pretty soon.